# Problems installing iOS PonyDebugger

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger). I am typing into the terminal the commands

`curl -sk https://cloud.github.com/downloads/square/PonyDebugger/bootstrap-ponyd.py | \
  python - --ponyd-symlink=/usr/local/bin/ponyd ~/Library/PonyDebugger`

and installing the script and the files with success.

However, when I type `ponyd serve --listen-interface=127.0.0.1`, i receive from the terminal `-bash: ponyd: command not found`.

Any solutions on how to move from this step? I already installed XCode command line tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the PonyDebugger developers here.  Try adding `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH.

An alternative is to run `ponyd` directly from the installation path.

`~/Library/PonyDebugger/bin/ponyd serve --listen-interface=127.0.0.1`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the Wen-Hao. If you could update the instructions in GitHub would help more people =) Two more question: I always start it via Terminal right? And once it is started, need to keep Terminal open?

Comment: Mountain Lion—unlike Lion—does not have /usr/local/bin in PATH by default.

Comment: @NatanR. Yes to both questions.  You can create a launch service to automatically run it on startup if you prefer, but it seems like overkill if you're just doing local debugging.